# Filter/Sort by Max Value Per ID in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of Objects that are structured like this:

```yaml
{
  id: String,
  userId: String,
  distance: Double,
  time: Double
}
```

In the array, there can be multiple entries for the same `userId` in the same distance. For example, the array may be:

```yaml
[
  { id: "1", userId: "1", distance: 100, time: 18.7 },
  { id: "2", userId: "1", distance: 100, time: 18.5 }, 
  { id: "3", userId: "2", distance: 100, time: 18.2 },
  { id: "4", userId: "2", distance: 200, time: 41.0 },
]
```

I want to filter and sort the array such that the array would only contain the fastest time for a certain distance per user. So if I wanted to use the above array to find 100 times it would simply return:

```yaml
[
  { id: "3", userId: "2", distance: 100, time: 18.2 },
  { id: "2", userId: "1", distance: 100, time: 18.5 },
]
```

I know I can use `.filter` to get it down to just the 100 times, and `.sort` to get the times in order, but I can't figure out how to limit to 1 entry per `userId`.

Comment: I would probably use `.reduce` to create a dictionary that maps user IDs to objects with the fastest time, then sort/filter off of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new [`grouped(by:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Grouped.md) function I added to [`swift-algorithms`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms) (A first-party pacakge hosted by Apple, which is like an accessory to the Swift standard library) for exactly this.

We can group up all the race results by their distance, and the user that ran them. Within each group of results, we'll select the one fastest time (of that user, for that distance). I call this `userPersonalRecords`.

From there, we can filter this down by distance to say, get everyone's best 100m sprint.

If we're doing this a lot, it might be worth grouping the race results by distance, and keeping the result arrays around. Altneratively, if you have *lots* of results, you can dump all these into a little SQLite DB, and do the same simple group/ordering with a query as-needed.

```swift
struct RaceResult {
    let id: String
    let userId: String
    let distance: Double
    let time: Double
}

let raceResults = [
    RaceResult(id: "1", userId: "1", distance: 100, time: 18.7),
    RaceResult(id: "2", userId: "1", distance: 100, time: 18.5),
    RaceResult(id: "3", userId: "2", distance: 100, time: 18.2),
    RaceResult(id: "4", userId: "2", distance: 200, time: 41.0),
]

// This simple little struct is just a workaround for tuples not being Hashable
struct UserDistance: Hashable {
    let userId: String
    let distance: Double
}

let userPersonalRecords = raceResults
    .grouped {
        UserDistance(userId: $0.userId, distance: $0.distance)
    }
    .mapValues { raceResults in raceResults.max(by: { $0.time < $1.time })! }
    .values

let fastest100MTimes = userPersonalRecords.filter { $0.distance == 100 }

for raceResult in fastest100MTimes {
    print(raceResult)
}
```

Comment: is there a package I need to import for this to work? I am getting "Value of type [RaceResult] has no member 'grouped'"

Comment: @J.Holliday First sentence of the answer, Swift Algorithms

Answer (score 0):

While operations like `sort`, `filter` and `map` can be useful and simplify your code, they are each going to iterate over the array.

Using Array "operations" you would need to:

- `filter` the array to include only the required distances
- `sort` the array by userid and time
- Use a `compactMap` to return only the first time for each user (Because of the sorting you know that the first time for each user is their fastest)
- Sort the "first times" array by time

This involves iterating the array (or a subset of it) twice and sorting it twice.

```
struct DistanceTime {
    let id: String
    let userId: String
    let distance: Double
    let time: Double
}

let times = [DistanceTime(id: "1", userId: "1", distance: 100, time: 18.7), DistanceTime(id: "2", userId: "1", distance: 100, time : 18.5),
DistanceTime(id: "3", userId: "2", distance: 100, time: 18.2), DistanceTime(id: "4", userId: "2", distance: 200, time: 41.0)]

func fastestTimesMap(for distance: Double, from distanceTimes:[DistanceTime]) -> [DistanceTime] {
    
    let filteredTimes = distanceTimes.filter { dt in
        return dt.distance == distance
    }
    
    let sortedTimes = filteredTimes.sorted { dt1, dt2 in
        if dt1.userId != dt2.userId {
            return dt1.userId < dt2.userId
        } else {
            return dt1.time < dt2.time
        }
    }
    
    var currentUser: String? = nil
    
    let output = sortedTimes.compactMap { dt in 
        if dt.userId != currentUser {
            currentUser = dt.userId
            return dt
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    return output.sorted { dt1, dt2 in
        return dt1.time < dt2.time
    }
}

let output = fastestTimesMap(for: 100, from: times)
```

An alternative approach is to use a `for` loop to iterate the array to:

- Filter the distances you are interested in
- Identify the fastest time for each user

After the loop is done you still need to sort the reduced array by `time` to find the fastest time:

```
func fastestTimes(for distance: Double, from distanceTimes:[DistanceTime]) -> [DistanceTime] {
    var times=[String:DistanceTime]()
    for dt in distanceTimes {
        if dt.distance == distance {
            if (times[dt.userId] == nil) {
                times[dt.userId] = dt
            }
            if dt.time < times[dt.userId]!.time {
                times[dt.userId] = dt
            }
        }
    }
    return Array(times.values).sorted { dt1, dt2 in 
        return dt1.time < dt2.time
    }
}

let output = fastestTimes(for: 100, from: times)
```

Not only is it less code, but you are now only traversing the full array once and sorting the reduced array once.

You could use `reduce` instead of a `for` loop but I think it would result in code that is less clear and it would have no performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

There's various ways to tackle this.

I'd probably restructure the data as a dictionary of structs keyed by userID.

If the distances were only a small set, (e.g. 50M, 100M, 500M, 1000M, 10,000M) I'd probably instead create my structs with arrays of races for each distance:

```
struct Race {
   let id: Int
   let time: Double
}

struct RaceUser {
    let userID: String
    let fiftyRaces: [Race]
    let hundredRaces: [Race]
    let fiveHundredRaces: [Race]
    let thousandRaces: [Race]
    let tenThousandRaces: [Race]
}
```

Then if you wanted the user with the fastest gift meter time you'd just iterate through all the key/value pairs comparing the first entry in the `fiftyRaces` for that user, looking for the one with the shortest time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, using `reduce(into:)`, that only iterates the array once

```
let selectedDistance = 100.0

let bestResults = array.reduce(into: [String: Object]()) {
    if $1.distance == selectedDistance {
        let old = $0[$1.userId]
        if old == nil || old!.time > $1.time { $0[$1.userId] = $1 }
    }
}.values
```